# jquery ajax servlet issue

Tags: jquery, arrays, servlets

hello i am using servlet jsp j query ajax.I used ajax to retrieve the name column from oracle db to auto complete.it works fine but after 10 -15 request my server goes down.i chake in both tomcat and j boss but the result is same.

### my code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    click();
});

function click() {
    alert("dik");
    $("#me").keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $("#me").val();
        if (e.keyCode > 64 && e.keyCode < 91) {
            callserver(value);
        }
    });
}

function callserver(value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%=cPath%>/lims/index",
        data: {
            action: "retrive autocomplete",
            name: value
        },
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000 //5 sec
    })
        .done(function (namelist) {
        var res = namelist.split(",");
        $("#me").autocomplete({
            source: res
        });
        res = null;
        //click();
    });
}
```

Comment: that problems belongs to your Apache Tomcat.learn about `Load Balancing,Tomcat Clustering`,etc

Comment: thnaks @hari mine is connection problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close the Data base connection.

```
// Clean-up environment
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
```

Comment: Use any JPA implementation for Automatic job & managing pool.